# print numbers from 1 to 1000 digit number - interview question

Tags: java, data-structures, pseudocode

I had an interview and I've been asked to print numbers from 1 to a 1000 digit number -

1,
2,
3,
.
.
.
.,
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999........

I couldn't solve it but I'm still looking for the best way to do it, because obviously, you cant use integers or floats in a case like this and because it's a job interview I couldn't use any libraries that can handle it.

Can anyone think of a good solution? preferably in Java/pseudocode.

Comment: It's Java, so `BigInteger` would be the simplest way to do it. Otherwise, an array of bytes, each representing one digit would do the trick.

Comment: If you can't use BigInteger, maybe you can use String in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursion (if only to print):

```
void digits(int count) {
    if (count < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid count: " + count);
    digits(count, "");
}

void digits(int count, String text) {
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println(text);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == 0 && text.isEmpty()) {
                digits(count-1, text);
            } else {
                digits(count-1, text+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `00000....00000` nor `000....0000xxxx` are valid.

Comment: It is also incorrect, it prints a null value (e.g. empty line) and does not print the last number (e.g. 10^1000). (I recall that this is a test to evaluate the quality of your answers)

Comment: You are right, I'm wrong with last value (not with the first one).

Comment: A note on time complexity / feasibility would be in order!

Answer (score 3):

> I had an interview and I've been asked to print numbers from 1 to a 1000 digit number

I guess the kind of answer they expected you to give is:

*"We need to print the numbers from 1 to 10^1000-1. Last year, $80e9 worth of processors were sold worldwide [1], even if one processor per dollar had been sold and each processor was a thousand times faster than the fastest of them all [2] and only one instruction was used to print each number and all these processors had been produced during the last 1000 years, still: 1e1000 / (80e9 - 1000 - 8.4e9 - 1000) > 1e973 seconds to print all the numbers. That is 10e956 billion years."*

Anyway, if you wish wait:

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger last = BigInteger.TEN.pow(1000);

while(n.compareTo(last) < 0) {
    System.out.println(n);
    n = n.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Assuming only `System.out.print` is able to use (String is a library, see [3]), a possible solution without copy over and over again strings, and with the expected output could be:

```
static void printDigits(int n) {
    ds(0, n, new byte[n]);
}

static void ds(int p, int k, byte[] d) {
    if (p < d.length) {                                     // if more digits to print
        for (byte i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                     // from digit 0 to 9
            d[p] = i;                                       //   set at this position
            ds(p + 1, i == 0 ? k : (p < k ? p : k), d);      //   populate next storing first non-zero
        }
    } else {
        if(k < d.length) {                                  // if is not zero
            if(k < d.length - 1 || d[d.length - 1] != 1)    // if is not one
                System.out.print(", ");                     // print separator
            for(int i = k; i < d.length; i++)               // for each digit
                System.out.print((char)('0' + d[i]));       // print
        }
    }
}
```

then, for `printDigits(5)` the output is

```
1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 99999
```

[1] https://epsnews.com/2020/09/14/total-microprocessor-sales-to-edge-slightly-higher-in-2020/

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_rate

[3] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: The interviewers forbid the use of BigInteger

Comment: @aviv then `String` must not be used (is a library) here my solution using only vanilla java